# Transform and Count Difference of Unique Customers over Time in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I've got a data frame in R that looks like the following:

```
cust = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "E", "A", "F", "A", "G")
period = as.Date(c("2013/1/1", "2013/1/1", "2013/1/1", "2013/1/2", "2013/1/2",
               "2013/1/2", "2013/1/3", "2013/1/3", "2013/1/4", "2013/1/4"))

df = data.frame(cust, period)
```

I wanted to transform it in a way that I can arrive in the following format as an output:

```
   period   NumCust_Initial  GainedCust  LostCust  NumCust_EndUpWith 
 1/1/2013                 3          NA        NA                 NA
 2/1/2013                 3           1         1                  3
 3/1/2013                 2           1         2                  2
 4/1/2013                 2           1         1                  2
```

The idea is that I'd arrive in a count of unique customers for each period. Then, I'd calculate the number of new customers acquired `GainedCust` and the number of customers lost `LostCust` all based on the previous period. Finally, we'd do a calculation that would get the

From `df` in `2/1/2013` I had 3 unique customers. I gained 1 (relative to `1/1/2013`) but lost another 1 (relative to `1/1/2013`) so I ended up with 3 customers (which is calculated as 3 from `NumCust_Initial` in `1/1/2013` plus the number of new customers `GainedCust` in `2/1/2013` and minus the number of lost customers `LostCust` in `2/1/2013`).

Similarly, we can see from `df` that in `3/1/2013` we started with 2 customers. We then gained 1 new customer (relative to `2/1/2013`) and lost 2 customers (relative to `2/1/2013`). And so forth and so on.

How can I perform all these transformations / calculations in R? I've tried looking at some of the functions in `dplyr` and `reshape2` but could not arrive in anything as of yet. Has anybody faced similar data transformation challenges in R before? How can I achieve the desired outcome in R?

Comment: Your gainedcust and lost cust columns do not make sense to me. You have three customers in day 1 and also 3 customers in day2. How will you have gain customer is 1 and lost custo is also 1?

Comment: Apologies, let me try to clarify: the `GainedCust` column is essentially a unique count of customers that appear in day 2 but not in day 1. Similarly, the `LostCust` is the number of unique customers that appear in day 1 but not in day 2. In the data frame `df` I tried to highlight this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `tidyr` and `dplyr`. Be sure to install the development version of `tidyr`.

```
# required packages
require(tidyr) # development version
require(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(current = TRUE) %>% 
  complete(period, cust, fill = list(current = FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(cust) %>% 
  mutate(gain = c(NA, diff(current))) %>%
  group_by(period) %>%
  summarise(GainedCust = sum(gain > 0), 
            LostCust = sum(gain < 0), 
            NumCust_EndUpWith = sum(current))
## Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
## 
##       period GainedCust LostCust NumCust_EndUpWith
## 1 2013-01-01         NA       NA                 3
## 2 2013-01-02          1        1                 3
## 3 2013-01-03          1        2                 2
## 4 2013-01-04          1        1                 2
```

Comment: if I happen to have duplicate Cust in the same period, how can I avoid double counting to get unique number of customers only? Also, I can't quite understand what the `mutate(gain = c(NA, diff(current)))` is doing? Thanks a lot. It's has helped a lot!